# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:1232 refused

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am trying to create an user registration from in android using ASP.Net web api but i got an error "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:1232 refused" how to solve it.. here below is code.... please help me

Here is my MainActivity class

```html
class NewUserRegistrationForm extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   progressDialog.dismiss();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute(); // To change body of overridden methods use
         // File | Settings | File Templates.
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
   progressDialog.setMessage("Registration...");
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
   progressDialog.show();
   
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   List<NameValuePair> args = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name.getText().toString()));
   args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
   args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile.getText()
     .toString()));
   args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address.getText()
     .toString()));
   args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category.getText()
     .toString()));
   JSONHttpClient jsonHttpClient = new JSONHttpClient();
   NewUserRegistration newUSerrstrn = (NewUserRegistration) jsonHttpClient
     .PostParams(ServiceUrl.REST_SERVICE_URL, args,
       NewUserRegistration.class);
   Log.d("args", args.toString());

   finish();
   return null;
  }

 }
```

here is my JSONHttpClient class

```html
public class JSONHttpClient {
    public <T> T PostObject(final String url, final T object, final Class<T> objectClass) {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
 
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(object));
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
 
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (httpEntity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
                }
 
                String resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
                return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);
 
            }
 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        return null;
    }
 
    public <T> T PostParams(String url, final List<NameValuePair> params, final Class<T> objectClass) {
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        return PostObject(url, null, objectClass);
    }
 
    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
 
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

here is my Web API class

```html
public class ServiceUrl {
//  public static final String REST_SERVICE_URL = "http://neta.luspl.com/api/person/PersonInsert/+newUSerrstrn+";
  
  public static final String REST_SERVICE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1232/api/";
     public static final String NewUserRegistration = REST_SERVICE_URL + "newUSerrstrn";

}
```

Here is My LogCat

```html
08-12 16:19:28.488: W/System.err(2791): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:1232 refused
08-12 16:19:28.526: I/Choreographer(2791): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 16:19:28.589: I/Choreographer(2791): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 16:19:28.789: I/Choreographer(2791): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 16:19:28.970: I/Choreographer(2791): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 16:19:29.207: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-12 16:19:29.208: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at com.survey.survey.JSONHttpClient.PostObject(JSONHttpClient.java:48)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at com.survey.survey.JSONHttpClient.PostParams(JSONHttpClient.java:76)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at com.survey.survey.MainActivity$NewUserRegistrationForm.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:107)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at com.survey.survey.MainActivity$NewUserRegistrationForm.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-12 16:19:29.209: W/System.err(2791):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-12 16:19:29.210: W/System.err(2791):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-12 16:19:29.218: W/System.err(2791):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-12 16:19:29.219: W/System.err(2791):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-12 16:19:29.237: I/Choreographer(2791): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 16:19:29.258: W/System.err(2791):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-12 16:19:29.259: W/System.err(2791): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 1232): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-12 16:19:29.265: W/System.err(2791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
08-12 16:19:29.266: W/System.err(2791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
08-12 16:19:29.266: W/System.err(2791):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
08-12 16:19:29.266: W/System.err(2791):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
08-12 16:19:29.266: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-12 16:19:29.266: W/System.err(2791):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-12 16:19:29.267: W/System.err(2791):  ... 16 more
08-12 16:19:29.305: W/System.err(2791): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-12 16:19:29.306: W/System.err(2791):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
08-12 16:19:29.306: W/System.err(2791):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
08-12 16:19:29.306: W/System.err(2791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
08-12 16:19:29.306: W/System.err(2791):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
08-12 16:19:29.307: W/System.err(2791):  ... 21 more
08-12 16:19:29.307: D/args(2791): [name=aa, email=aa, mobile=aa, address=aa, category=aa]
```

Comment: 1) Do you add INTERNET permission to manifest?
2) Do you setup firewall for your service? You can try open your service URL in web browser on device to check it.

Comment: First of all, from what device you're trying to access this address? If you're trying to access it from a real device not an emulator - you should use the real IP address.

Comment: yes  i added INTERNET permission in manifest.

Comment: Is your server running at this address 10.0.2.2:1232 ¿? You should use the IP address of the server

Comment: right now i am running it on emulator

Comment: @vikassingh which emulator you're using? The build in or Genymotion? (sorry for jos :) )

Comment: @vikas singh And what is your server address?

Comment: @Seishin maybe you were wrong with the name that you were asking ;)

Comment: when i used server IP address i got an error=====android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.survey.survey.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1033ab2a V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-228,88} that was originally added here

Comment: Have you checked that on localhost port 1232 on your dev-computer runs an HTTP server? Test it with telnet if the port is open.

Comment: @vikassingh could you debug if you the connection is stablished? Hopefully this is an after error :)

Comment: @vikassingh which emulator are you using? If you're using the standard emulator your localhost IP will be the one you're using - 10.0.2.2, but if you're using Genymotion, it will be - 10.0.3.2. Also check if the port is the same and your OS firewall isn't blocking the requests.

Comment: @seishin Now i am using my server IP address with port no then i got this type of error==org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Comment: @vikassingh first of all where is located your server? On your local machine or somewhere else? If you're on your local machine you should use either 10.0.2.2 (standard emulator) or 10.0.3.2 (genymotion) and check if the port is the correct one.

Comment: @seishin i am on my local machine and used 10.0.2.2 but still not working..i got error== org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

Comment: any one can suggest me any different way, how to call web api in android

Comment: @vikassingh use a networking library like Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)